# Rendering Angularjs specfic view without header and footer

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-view

So all of my pages use the index.html to render pages and in the index.html, my code is structured so that all views render in the div with the ng-view="" tag as:

```
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController" style="border-bottom: #ab2328 3px solid;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" ng-click="navbarExpanded = !navbarExpanded">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                </button>
                <a ng-show="!isSWA" class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.naviabenefits.com" target="_blank"><img style="height: 37px;" src="ppt/assets/navia.png"></a>
                <a ng-show="isSWA" class="navbar-brand" href="http://pebb.naviabenefits.com/" target="_blank"><img style="height: 37px;" src="ppt/assets/navia.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="!navbarExpanded">
                <ul ng-show="!isSWA" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ng-show="authentication.isAdmin"><a href="#/admin/ppt">admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/products-and-services/" target="_blank">products + services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/about/" target="_blank">about us</a></li>`
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/testimonials/" target="_blank">testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/careers/" target="_blank">careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/news/" target="_blank">news</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/blog/" target="_blank">blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.naviabenefits.com/contact/" target="_blank">contact us</a></li>
                    <li ng-show="authentication.isAuth"><a id="signOut" href="#/logout" >sign out <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div ng-view="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" role="navigation" ng-controller="indexController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footerLinks">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

So I have a couple of pages that I want to render **without** the header and footer, but still keep some of the other pathing.

This "plain" page has its own controller and all and my routing for it in my app.js looks like:

```
$routeProvider.when("/claimReceipt-plain", {
    controller: "claimReceiptController",
    templateUrl: "ppt/views/claims/claimReceipt-plain.html"
});
```

How can I do this within this index.html and not have the header and footers render, but me more or less, its own page?

Comment: Have you tried making the header and footer it's own view? Maybe just make header and footer a component and pass different directives for different views in your app.js.

Comment: Also, curious are you using ui-router and are you opposed if not?

Comment: I am trying to keep it simply within the constraints I have. Is there not a way to do with another view that does not utilize the header and footer containers?

Comment: You want to conditionally show the header and footer, correct?

Comment: I simply did it in the view applying display: none;

Comment: Why not just use angular's ng-if, better I think for your situation. It'll save the reference to the elements place on the DOM but it wont load them. You could use the view name to conditionally load them.

Comment: did this work out for you?

Comment: Yes, just display: none did the trick as well. Suppose I could have used the ng-if as well.

Answer (score 0):

Define a scope level Boolean variable on the page controller where you don't want the header and use ng-show directive to apply condition on the header div tag.

Comment: Sorry I forgot your header is a part of index page which is rendered using main controller so you cannot control controller scope variable from view controllers. 

May be you should try passing values from view controller(where you don't want header) to main controller setting the display value to false and use it in ng-show.

Comment: Use this link to see how you can exchange values between controller:
https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services

Sorry couldn't provide code snippet right now. Try this if you don't come up with solution, will try to write a snippet.